# Making a pictureBox inside of a groupBox transparent

Tags: c#

So i've got a groupBox with a picture 1 inside of it. So i need to add smaller picture 2 over the picture 1, but picture 2's background mustn't overlap picture 1.

I've tried this approach:

```
InitializeComponent();
groupBox.Controls.Add(pictureBox2);
pictureBox2.Location = new Point(0, 0);
pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

and this

```
InitializeComponent();
pictureBox1.Controls.Add(pictureBox2);
pictureBox2.Location = new Point(0, 0);
pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

but neither work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"So i need to add smaller picture 2 over the picture 1, but picture 2 mustn't overlap picture 1."* That statement seems mutually exclusive...

Comment: The latter might work but you don't really explain what you want to achive.

Comment: @RonBeyer i wrote it in a hurry. The picture 2's background mustn't overlap with picture 1 (background of picture 2 must be transparent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the parent control of the picture box. The transparent background that is displayed is that of the parent control.

```
InitializeComponent();
groupBox.Controls.Add(pictureBox2);
pictureBox2.Parent = pictureBox1;
pictureBox2.Location = new Point(0, 0);
pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

Comment: thanks a bunch. However, why do i need the `Initializecomponent();` part? It kind of screws up rest of my code.

Comment: So i tried to make it work, and somehow succeeded. I'm still an amateur so this was all new to me. I made a new `private void` method in the designer, which contained all of "pictureBox1" entries from `InitializeComponent()` and referenced that method instead of `InitializeComponent()` in your solution. I have no idea how, but it works.

Comment: @FedjaMladenovic It is not recommended to modify the designer file. Can you tell me what are you trying to solve by modifying the designer file?

Comment: You see, i have a huge groupBox. Depending on your selection of specific parameters, only a portions of groupBox should be displayed when the program is executed. So, when i call the `InitializeComponent()`, and execute the program, i can't get those smaller portions of the groupBox, only groupBox as a whole.

Comment: I guess that's because i modified groupBox in the Form.cs, but not in the designer. So, when i need to execute a program, i must not call the entire designer (since some parts of it are changed in Form.cs but not in the designer) but only the parts of it that weren't changed. That's how i figured out making another method similar to `InitializeComponent()` that calls only the properties that i need (In this case all entries in designer that contain pictureBox1)

Comment: I'm really a begginner, and i can't explain my thoughts any better, i beg your pardon for any inconvenience

Comment: You might need to control this situation by working with the control properties. It would be better if you frame a new question with the problem you are facing, and the approach you are using.

Comment: I just did. Thanks alot anyways, you were really helpful. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish this try the following:

```
InitializeComponent();
pictureBox1.Controls.Add(pictureBox2);
pictureBox2.Location = new Point(0, 0);
pictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
pictureBox1.SendToBack();
pictureBox2.BringToFront();
```

used .SendToBack() for the one on the back and .BringToFront() for the one on the front.

Comment: The Transparent background will still be that of the parent control, which is groupbox in your solution.

Comment: @Harsh How so?  They added it to the Picture1 Controls collection.  That sets the Parent property.  The answer you posted moves PictureBox2's parent from the GroupBox to PictureBox1.  No different.

Comment: @LarsTech My bad. I somehow read that Controls.Add was on groupbox. Taking my comment back. Thanks.